# GAE application not running latest server.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have deployed a very simple node.js application to Google App Engine (GAE). Initial deploy went smooth and it was serving pages from /public as expected. However, I was missing the log entry from the listen function that I was expecting to see so I started to deploy updated versions to find out why the log entry was not appearing.

Since then I have deployed several new versions (`gcloud app deploy`) but whatever I deploy in the server.js does not seem to update the application at all.

Initial code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

If I change `app.use(express.static('public'));` to another directory like

`app.use(express.static('publicnew'));` it still serves the pages correctly in GAE, which I would not expect.

I have even tried just throwing an error on the first line but the server is still running after a new deploy...

If I update the html pages in /public those changes are reflected when I load the page in the browser, so the deploy is working, it's just that it's not the latest version of server.js that's started up.

Also, if I run server.js locally in my terminal it provides the expected result so the code itself is correct.

I do not believe this to be a caching issue as it's not related to the pages being served. I have in any case waited over a day between test. I have also deleted all previous versions in the cloud console. There is only the latest one running.

Anyone has experienced this and can explain?

Comment: Try running ```gcloud app deploy --no-cache``` and/or ```gcloud app deploy --verbosity='info```. The former ensures the build is done without reusing caching (means it will take longer to build/deploying) while the latter prints more information to the screen (log) so you have more debugging information